# 1080 ti not using 100% vram

Tags: claymore, nvidia

I have a Nvidai GTX 1080ti overclocked and I have a dedicated gpu memory of 11GB and when I see the meter or check the usage of the graphic card while mining using claymore it is around 32MH/S and it is using upto 75% of vram and the dedicated GPU memory usage is around 3GB. It is not using 11GB.

So, my question here is when I used GUI Miner for bitcoin it was running at 1.7 GH/S and claymore is running at 32MH/s is this correct or I have done anything wrong? and I am getting a constant 10% stale shares, so, do I have to keep my GPU overclocked or under clocked or keep as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum uses EthHash algorithm and Bitcoin uses double SHA256 algorithm as proof of work.

You cannot compare them because those algorithms have a very different design. EthHash was designed to be ASIC resistant and because of that it is memory hard.

[EthHash](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash) uses a large data set to work. It is called the DAG, it should grown with time and currently is around 3Gb. I guess the algorithm used by the miner to calculate ethhash doesn't need much more memory, and likely will not need the full 12 GBytes from your card.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Ismael, can I ask you one more thing, if it is not using my 100% of my card then am I going to get rewarded less or equally?, because the mh/s matters the most in mining right. So, I am getting less than what my card can do.

Comment: Usually you get rewards for the solutions founds, it doesn't matter GPU, memory, or bandwidth usage.